# How to view json file in to web view flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to retrieve json file from a given url into web view flutter but i faced issue the web view is displaying data with html tags

I used web plugin from pub .dev

initialUrl: "some url it works'
,

onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller){

```
_controller.complete(controller);
```

no error

Comment: Wrap your content in `<pre>` tag.

Comment: where can i use this tag ,i used what you see what you get editor ,in android we can change load data int meme: text/html and utf-8 but in in flutter i have no idea